# Mockwebserver where url cannot be changed?

Tags: mocking, android-testing, mockwebserver

I am using mockwebserver for android testing. I am able to mock my network services that uses retrofit by doing

```
 NetworkServiceHelper.init(String.valueOf(server.url("/")));
```

However, I am unable to mock request for web request made by other SDKs such as Atlas-Layer that have base url https://api.layer.com/apps/.

I did the following but getting request count still 0.

```
MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
mockWebServer.url("https://api.layer.com/apps");
mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), "temp.json")));
getConversation("demo", "asdf"); // makes web service all using Layer SDK
mockWebServer.getRequestCount(); // Returns 0 instead of 1
```